# Appealing flags marked as invalid

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, appeal

What's the best course of action when certain flags you have raised get marked as invalid, but you still believe them to be valid?

**The questions I tagged as duplicates:**

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010794/311220 -> [How to add a namespace to an attribute in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374443/311220)

[Convert HTML entities to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907812/311220) -> [Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57708/311220)

[pinyin in google translate API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887247/311220) -> [Get Chinese Romanization from Google Translate API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750093/get-chinese-romanization-from-google-translate-api)

*(note: for the first two questions I just edited the titles to better match the question. When the questions were first flagged the titles were more vague)*

If these aren't duplicates, an explanation of why they are not would be helpful so that I know when not to flag questions in future.

Comment: I agree with the first two (and have voted to close as dupes), the third one might be different enough.

Answer (score 1):

[You should stop worrying and love dupes.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Besides, you shouldn't be flagging as dupe unless it is a 100% dupe (same text) which indicates something else is wrong.  You should be *voting to close as dupe.*

If you don't have enough rep to do that yet, perhaps you should be spending more time answering questions and less time flagging dupes.

Comment: If you have enough rep to vote to close then you can't flag as dupe, the option doesn't exist anymore. I got the impression flagging as "doesn't belong here" is when a user wants to close but can't, so if they "should be voting to close" they should also be flagging to close -- it's just which ability they have based on their reputation

Comment: Thanks, the link to Jeff's thoughts on dupes was very useful! `"perhaps you should be spending more time answering questions"` .. I personally thought I was doing quite a bit of question answering :(

Comment: Flagging as dupe (and also commenting on the question, because that's not automatic with a flag) is perfectly reasonable behavior if you consider the question to be a dupe, and don't have enough reputation to vote to close (or have run out of close votes).

Comment: @Gilles: [Except, you should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).  My biggest problem with dupe flags is that the mod queue is choked with them, and only a small percentage would qualify as actual duplicates.  That, and dealing with incorrect closures and the massive amount of fanny pain generated.  I just think that if you don't have enough rep to flag as dupe, you most likely don't get the distinction between good dupes and bad dupes.

Comment: But now that 10kers can act on dupe and other close flags, you ♦ can mostly ignore them — let them be for a day or two, then delete them.